# LDAP group mapping in Grafana

Tags: ldap, grafana, openldap

I need some help. I'm able to log in to the system with my LDAP users but all of them have the Admin role although I've configured the LDAP group mappings.
I think that this could be related with the actual schema I've in my LDAP. I'm far from being an LDAP expert, so I would like to receive some help from you.

This is a common user account of LDAP:

```
#rmartinez, people, domain.com
dn: uid=rmartinez,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=domain
cn: Ricardo Martinez
gidNumber: 100
givenName: Ricardo
homeDirectory: /home/rmartinez
loginShell: /bin/bash
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
sn: Martinez
uid: rmartinez
uidNumber: 10009
userPassword:: e3NzaGF9dWN0RGJ1Njg4ejZPeittYUxrdlRoZWUrM2VWUFdFcFpVQT09
```

This is one of the groups mapped to Grafana:

```
# Directores, group, domain.com
dn: cn=Directores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: Directores
gidNumber: 10002
member: uid=sbenito,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
member: uid=jsaez,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
member: uid=rsanchez,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: groupOfNames
userPassword:: e3NzaGF9cmhxUVdhWmdZNy83NHM3cGxPYVd6VFFDQVlOWlRsUk5TZz09
```

And this is how my ldap.toml looks like:

```
# To troubleshoot and get more log info enable ldap debug logging in grafana.ini
#[log]
#filters = ldap:debug
verbose_logging = true
[[servers]]
# Ldap server host (specify multiple hosts space separated)
host = "dc01.domain.com"
# Default port is 389 or 636 if use_ssl = true
port = 389
# Set to true if ldap server supports TLS
use_ssl = true
# Set to true if connect ldap server with STARTTLS pattern (create connection in insecure, then upgrade to secure connection with TLS)
start_tls = true
# set to true if you want to skip ssl cert validation
ssl_skip_verify = true
# set to the path to your root CA certificate or leave unset to use system defaults
 root_ca_cert = "/etc/ldap/certs/caskmf.pem"
# Authentication against LDAP servers requiring client certificates
 client_cert = "/etc/ldap/certs/dc01srvcert.pem"
 client_key = "/etc/ldap/certs/dc01key.pem"

# Search user bind dn
bind_dn = "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com"
# Search user bind password
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with triple quotes. Ex """#password;"""
bind_password = 'admin'

# User search filter, for example "(cn=%s)" or "(sAMAccountName=%s)" or "(uid=%s)"
search_filter = "(uid=%s)"

# An array of base dns to search through
search_base_dns = ["dc=domain,dc=com"]

## For Posix or LDAP setups that does not support member_of attribute you can define the below settings
## Please check grafana LDAP docs for examples
group_search_filter = "(&(objectClass=posixGroup))"
group_search_base_dns = ["ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com"]
group_search_filter_user_attribute = "uid"

# Specify names of the ldap attributes your ldap uses
[servers.attributes]
name = "givenName"
surname = "sn"
username = "cn"
member_of = "memberOf"
#email =  "email"

# Map ldap groups to grafana org roles
[[servers.group_mappings]]
group_dn = "cn=Administradores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com"
org_role = "Admin"
# To make user an instance admin  (Grafana Admin) uncomment line below
grafana_admin = true
# The Grafana organization database id, optional, if left out the default org (id 1) will be used
# org_id = 1

[[servers.group_mappings]]
group_dn = "cn=Operadores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com"
org_role = "Editor"

[[servers.group_mappings]]
# If you want to match all (or no ldap groups) then you can use wildcard
group_dn = "cn=Directores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com"
org_role = "Viewer"
```

Please, could you help me? I've tried almost everything. I think that this is related because users do not have any attribute that makes reference to the group they belong to.
This is the log:

```
Dec 18 09:25:55 persephone grafana-server[4668]: t=2019-12-18T09:25:55+0100 lvl=info msg="LDAP enabled, reading config file" logger=ldap file=/etc/grafana/ldap.toml
Dec 18 09:25:55 persephone grafana-server[4668]: t=2019-12-18T09:25:55+0100 lvl=info msg="Searching for user's groups" logger=ldap filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup))"
Dec 18 09:25:55 persephone grafana-server[4668]: t=2019-12-18T09:25:55+0100 lvl=dbug msg="LDAP users found" logger=ldap users="([]*models.ExternalUserInfo) (len=1 cap=1) {\n (*models.ExternalUserInfo)(0xc0000da510)({\n  OAuthToken: (*oauth2.Token)(<nil>),\n  AuthModule: (string) (len=4) \"ldap\",\n  AuthId: (string) (len=38) \"uid=pgambarte,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com\",\n  UserId: (int64) 0,\n  Email: (string) \"\",\n  Login: (string) (len=14) \"Pilar Gambarte\",\n  Name: (string) (len=14) \"Pilar Gambarte\",\n  Groups: ([]string) (len=3 cap=4) {\n   (string) (len=37) \"cn=Operadores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com\",\n   (string) (len=42) \"cn=Administradores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com\",\n   (string) (len=37) \"cn=Directores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com\"\n  },\n  OrgRoles: (map[int64]models.RoleType) (len=1) {\n   (int64) 1: (models.RoleType) (len=5) \"Admin\"\n  },\n  IsGrafanaAdmin: (*bool)(0xc00082fa20)(true),\n  IsDisabled: (bool) false\n })\n}\n"
Dec 18 09:25:55 persephone grafana-server[4668]: t=2019-12-18T09:25:55+0100 lvl=dbug msg="user auth token created" logger=auth tokenId=14 userId=2 clientIP=10.0.2.2 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36" authToken=f8152859f8f2421705b2b967a742bcfbfb7ec4d5e0ef0cebe9575dbb399a54c9
Dec 18 09:25:55 persephone grafana-server[4668]: t=2019-12-18T09:25:55+0100 lvl=info msg="Successful Login" logger=http.server User="Pilar Gambarte"
Dec 18 09:25:55 persephone grafana-server[4668]: t=2019-12-18T09:25:55+0100 lvl=dbug msg="seen token" logger=auth tokenId=14 userId=2 clientIP=10.0.2.2 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36" authToken=f8152859f8f2421705b2b967a742bcfbfb7ec4d5e0ef0cebe9575dbb399a54c9
Dec 18 09:25:55 persephone grafana-server[4668]: t=2019-12-18T09:25:55+0100 lvl=dbug msg="Updating last user_seen_at" logger=context userId=2 orgId=1 uname="Pilar Gambarte" user_id=2
```

Thank you so much.
Regards.

Comment: Can you confirm that pgambarte is not in the administrators (Administradores) group ? Else, can you provide the log of what happens when someone not in the administrators group logs in .  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@tomgalpin This is the log of a user who belongs to Directores group instead of Administradores:

```
Dec 18 14:15:48 persephone grafana-server[1730]: t=2019-12-18T14:15:48+0100 lvl=info msg="LDAP enabled, reading config file" logger=ldap file=/etc/grafana/ldap.toml
Dec 18 14:15:48 persephone grafana-server[1730]: t=2019-12-18T14:15:48+0100 lvl=info msg="Searching for user's groups" logger=ldap filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup))"
Dec 18 14:15:48 persephone grafana-server[1730]: t=2019-12-18T14:15:48+0100 lvl=dbug msg="LDAP users found" logger=ldap users="([]*models.ExternalUserInfo) (len=1 cap=1) {\n (*models.ExternalUserInfo)(0xc00047d680)({\n  OAuthToken: (*oauth2.Token)(<nil>),\n  AuthModule: (string) (len=4) \"ldap\",\n  AuthId: (string) (len=36) \"uid=sbenito,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com\",\n  UserId: (int64) 0,\n  Email: (string) \"\",\n  Login: (string) (len=11) \"Sara Benito\",\n  Name: (string) (len=11) \"Sara Benito\",\n  Groups: ([]string) (len=3 cap=4) {\n   (string) (len=37) \"cn=Operadores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com\",\n   (string) (len=42) \"cn=Administradores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com\",\n   (string) (len=37) \"cn=Directores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com\"\n  },\n  OrgRoles: (map[int64]models.RoleType) (len=1) {\n   (int64) 1: (models.RoleType) (len=5) \"Admin\"\n  },\n  IsGrafanaAdmin: (*bool)(0xc0005c5fc0)(true),\n  IsDisabled: (bool) false\n })\n}\n"
Dec 18 14:15:48 persephone grafana-server[1730]: t=2019-12-18T14:15:48+0100 lvl=info msg="Successful Login" logger=http.server User="Sara Benito"
```

And here is the Administradores group ldapsearch output. As you can see pgambarte belongs to it. the issue is that Grafana is not filtering correctly the membership of the users to the different groups and all the users, no matter what group belongs to, have the same role: admin.
Pgambarte is in Administradores Group:

```
# Administradores, group, domain.com
dn: cn=Administradores,ou=group,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: Administradores
gidNumber: 10001
member: uid=pgambarte,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
member: uid=rmartin,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
member: uid=rmartinez,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
member: uid=pgomez,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
member: uid=jramirez,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
```

Thank you for your assistance.